# How to call a scheduler inside a controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, controller

I am having a rest Controller and inside the REST Controller I wanted to call a method which updates an array list ob objects every 5 seconds.I update the list every five seconds so that I want check one of the request parameter with the array list data.
Below is my Controller Class

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

List<Model1> list1= new ArrayList<Model1>();
List<Model2> list2= new ArrayList<Model2>();

@Autowired
@Qualifier("restTemplateapi")
private RestTemplate restTemplateapi;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplateapi() {


    RestTemplateBuilder builderapi = new RestTemplateBuilder();
    RestTemplate buildapi = builderapi.build();

    return buildapi;
}



@Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
public void get_list2(){
    list2 = Arrays.asList(restTemplatestreetapi.getForObject("http:dataurl for list2", Model2[].class));
    System.out.println(list2.get(0).getStatus()+ " is the staus of the first element:" );





}






@RequestMapping(value="/api",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getlist1(@RequestParam("lat")double lat,@RequestParam("lon") double lon,@RequestParam("id") int id){






    list1=get_api(lat,lon,id);


    status status_object=new status();
    Map <String,List<Model1>> map1= new HashMap<String,List<Model1>>();
    List<status> statuslist=new ArrayList<status>();
    status_object.setCode("hi");
    status_object.setMessage("good api call");
    statuslist.add(status_object);





    streetapilist.put("data",map1);
    Map<String,List<status>> map2=new HashMap<String,List<status>>();
    statusmap.put("status", map2);



    Map<String, Object> combinedMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    combinedMap.putAll(map1);
    combinedMap.putAll(map2);






    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(combinedMap,HttpStatus.OK);
}
@ResponseBody   

public List<Model1>  get_api(double lat,double lon,int id,String email){
    List<Model1> list1 = Arrays.asList(restTemplatestreetapi.getForObject("http:dataurl for list1, Model1[].class));

    return list1;



}

}
```

So in my controller every 5 seconds I want to update my list2 because whenever a call is made to controller it want to check the list2 and then proceed to return list1.

But now my sheduled method get_list2 is not triggered even once and nothing is printing in the console.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@EnableScheduling` ensures that a background task executor is created. Without it, nothing gets scheduled.

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ shi Oh I totally forgot to enable it.Thanks a lot